# problema com soma parseInt()

Tags: javascript

estou tentando somar mais "1" com parseInt() ao numero mas ele sempre me retorna o numero original com o "1" ao lado dele, por exemplo 10 + 1 ele me retorna 101 (acerto mizeravi). Obs: Estou usando o split porque na minha funçao completa eu retorno para varias div's diferentes valores diferentes.

```js
 function teste(conteudo) {
      dados = conteudo.split('|');
      var adicicaoEstoque = parseInt(dados[1] + 1);
      document.getElementById(dados[0]).innerHTML = adicicaoEstoque;
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="teste('resultado|10')">adicione + 1</button>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O correto seria primeiro converter o "10" e depois adicionar 1, senão ele faz a operação "10" + "1" que dá "101".

Veja assim:

```
var adicicaoEstoque = parseInt(dados[1]) + 1;
```

```js
function teste(conteudo) {
    dados = conteudo.split('|');
    var adicicaoEstoque = parseInt(dados[1]) + 1;
    document.getElementById(dados[0]).innerHTML = adicicaoEstoque;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="teste('resultado|10')">adicione + 1</button>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```